# How to escape asterisk (*) in MySQL in a REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

I tried matching keywords with `REGEXP` in MySQL as following:

```
-- Match "fitt*", the asterisk "*" is expected to be matched as-is

> select 'aaaa fitt* bbb' regexp '[[:<:]]fitt\*[[:>:]]'; -- return 1, ok
> select 'aaaa fitttttt* bbb' regexp '[[:<:]]fitt\*[[:>:]]'; -- return 1 as well, but should return 0

> select 'aaaa fitt* bbb' regexp '[[:<:]]fitt\\*[[:>:]]'; -- return 0, failed
```

How to escape the asterisk (`*`) in order to exactly match the character `*`?

Comment: The problem isn't with the asterisk, it's with `[[:>:]]`. That only matches at a word boundary, but there's no word boundary between `*` and space because `*` isn't a word character.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. But how to match the word `fitt*` with REGEXP?

Comment: I changed the title based on the debate between @Barmar and myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\\*` is the correct way to match the asterisk. But `[[:>:]]` won't match after it, because that only matches between a word character and a non-word character, and `*` is not a word character. Instead, you need to match a non-word character there explicitly. You also need an alternative for the end of line, since that's the other type of word boundary.

```
> select 'aaaa fitt* bbb' regexp '[[:<:]]fitt\\*([^[:alnum:]]|$)'; -- returns 1
> select 'aaaa fitttttt* bbb' regexp '[[:<:]]fitt\\*([^[:alnum:]]|$)'; -- returns 0
```

Another way to match the asterisk explicitly is by putting it in a character class.

```
> select 'aaaa fitt* bbb' regexp '[[:<:]]fitt[*]([^[:alnum:]]|$)'; -- returns 1
> select 'aaaa fitttttt* bbb' regexp '[[:<:]]fitt[*]([^[:alnum:]]|$)'; -- returns 0
```

Comment: No.  `\\*` means zero or more backslashes.  Your test _happens_ to work because it found zero backslashes, then a `*`, which is not an 'alnum'.

Comment: @RickJames The first backslash escapes the second backslash in the string. That resulting backslash escapes the `*` in the regexp.

Comment: If I put a backslash in the string being tested, it doesn't match it.

Comment: Was the backslash in the string escaped?  `SELECT 'a\b' REGEXP 'a.b', 'a\\b' REGEXP 'a.b';` --> 0, 1.

Comment: @RickJames `select 'aaaa fitt\\* bbb' regexp '[[:<:]]fitt\\*([^[:alnum:]]|$)';` -> 0`

Comment: Let's simplify the examples.  `select '\\' regexp '^\\*$';` fails; `select '\\' regexp '^\\\\*$';` succeeds.  I read that as an extra level of "unescaping" is needed inside the `regexp`.

Comment: Let's simplify: `select '*' regexp '^\*$'` gets an error, `select '*' regexp '^\\*$'` succeeds.

Comment: The error is because the string is unescaped, resulting in the invalid regexp `^*$`.

Answer (score 1):

There could be 3 problems:

Item 1:  The answer to the title question is either of these:

```
\\*  (in the regexp)
[*]
```

Item 2:  `\\\\*` *may* be needed if you are coming from some client that first unescapes the backslash before feeding it to MySQL, which still needs a backslash.  However, as written (without any client code), `\\\\*` is treated as zero or more backslashes.

Item 3:  @Barmar's answer focused on why `[[:>:]]` is incorrect.

Comment: `\\*` is needed if you're writing the string literally in the query, since MySQL itself first unescapes the backslash.

Comment: And if you're doing it in a client programming language that also unescapes, you need to double it again, e.g. `$sql = "SELECT 'aaaa fitt* bbb' regexp '[[:<:]]fitt\\\\*([^[:alnum:]]|$)'";` in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar and Zelong -- I'm testing in the mysql commandline tool; what are you testing in?